# Adding rows to DataGridView programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a `DatGridView` to which I add new rows. The first column of every row is an image the indicates whether the rest of the row has been completed. To keep track of this each row has a List-like object attached to it that counts the number of completed fields, then changes the image if enough fields have been completed. This works exactly as expected when the user is adding rows in the GUI, however I run into problems when I try to add new rows programmatically.

When a new row is created, the `DataGridViewImageCell` from the first column is added to the custom class that keeps track of the completed fields.

Here is the code to add a new row:

```
//initiate the new row
object[] buffer = new object[13];
buffer[0] = nullImage; //a blank image

for (int i = 1; i < buffer.Length; i++)
{
     buffer[i] = String.Empty;
}

rowID = DataGridView1.Rows.Add(buffer);
```

Here is the `RowAdded` code:

```
    private void DataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewImageCell tmp = (DataGridViewImageCell)DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[0];
        DataGridView1ValidateFields.AddRow(tmp); //custom class to keep track of completed fields
    }
```

The custom class contains a List of `DataGridViewImageCells` dgvic; here is its' `AddRow` method:

```
    private List<object> dgvic = new List<object>();
    public void AddRow(DataGridViewImageCell p)
    {
        items.Add(new List<int>());//List of ints to keep track of completed fields
        dgvic.Add(p);
    }
```

When I enter the debugger (while adding rows programmatically) I can see that each time I add a new row the `DataGridViewImageCells` stored in `dgvic` are all from the most recent row. For instance after adding 3 rows, I'd expect the 3 `DataGridViewImageCells` to be from rows 0, 1 and 2; however all of them are from row 2.

It looks to me that `RowCount` is still tied to each `DataGridViewCell`, and as `RowCount` increments the cell changes. If this were the case though, how come it works through the GUI? Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is your dgv databound?

Comment: @Marius: no, it's not. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Are you adding multiple rows at once? Ie `DataGridView1.Rows.AddRange(<list_of_rows>);`?

Comment: @gzaxx: no, the only place I add rows is through the code above.

Comment: Try if it helps to change this line: `DataGridViewImageCell tmp = (DataGridViewImageCell)DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[0];` to this one: `DataGridViewImageCell tmp = (DataGridViewImageCell)DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0];`

Comment: Could we see a little more about dgvic?

Comment: @gzaxx: Tried it, still the same problem.

Comment: @glace: That's really all there is to dgvic. When an int is added to `Items[rows.Count]`  a check is performed to see if enough items have been added to 'complete' the row; if so the `DataGridViewImageCell` in `dgvic[rows.Count]` is changed.

Comment: @glace: I added one other line; `dvic` is a list of `objects`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change yours `AddedRows` event as follows:

```
private void DataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = e.RowIndex;
    for (int i = 0; i < e.RowCount; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewImageCell tmp = (DataGridViewImageCell)DataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0];
        DataGridView1ValidateFields.AddRow(tmp);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That actually does work! Can you explain why this works and my previous attempt didn't?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure. I ran into similar problem but when I was adding an array of rows to DataGridView not only one. My guess is that this event is not fired instantly after adding row (waiting for next?) and that is why RowCount was already incremented and then event fired for 3 rows added. But that is only a guess, tomorrow I will try to check this theory and will come back to you with answer (hopefully :) ).